# Magento Event Observer Scope

Tags: magento

Im working on this Observer for pulling parameters out of the URL on page load and was hoping someone could help me figure out how to get this working how I want it. I only want this observer firing on frontend page loads and not backend. If I keep the scope set to frontend like below it doesnt work. If I change it to global it fires fine. How can I remedy this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <MyCompany_Mailchimp>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyCompany_Mailchimp>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <Mailchimp_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>MyCompany_Mailchimp_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>catchMailchimpParams</method>
                </Mailchimp_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>    
    </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like event controller_front_init_routers dispatches before front scope is initialized. So if it is possible, you should choose some other event, which fires later. I don't quite understand, what your task is, but maybe event controller_action_predispatch is acceptable?

Comment: My task is to check if there are some parameters in the URL and if so set them into a cookie for the user. So I need to read http://mycompany.com/product-page.html?mc=3434 and take the value of "mc". I have all of this correctly working with controller_front_init_routers but I dont need it to be global thats all. I will look into controller_action_predispatch.

Comment: If you're getting parameters by Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam(), then it also should work with controller_action_predispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen to controller_action_layout_load_before event, instead of controller_front_init_routers. This event is triggered only on frontend. For more information about Magento events list, read [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events).

Comment: Please notify me if you encounter some problem :)